# How to plot data, time on x-axis not datetime

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

```
   id        timestamp          energy
0   a   2012-03-18 10:00:00     0.034
1   b   2012-03-20 10:30:00     0.052
2   c   2013-05-29 11:00:00     0.055
3   d   2014-06-20 01:00:00     0.028
4   a   2015-02-10 12:00:00     0.069
```

I want to plot these data like below.
just time on x-axis, not date nor datetime.

because I want to see the values per each hour.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u73eJ.png

but this code plot like this.

```
plt.plot(df['timestamp'], df['energy'])
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd6NL.png

I tried some codes but they just format the X data hide date part and plot like second graph.

+ df['timestamp'] is datetime type.

what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: try replacing `df['timestamp']` with `df['timestamp'].dt.time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert your datetime into time, if your `df["timestamp"]` is already in datetime format then

```py
df["time"] = df["timestamp"].map(lambda x: x.time())
plt.plot(df['time'], df['energy'])
```

if `df["timestamp"]` is of type string then you can add one more line in front as `df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])`

Update: look like matplotlib does not accept `time` types, just convert to `string`

```py
df["time"] = df["timestamp"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
plt.scatter(df['time'], df['energy'])
```

Comment: I already tried converting date time to time
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp])
df['time] = df['timestamp].dt.time
like this.
but when I plot, TypeError : float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time' occurred even I tested with your answer code.

Comment: look like matplotlib does not allow "time" type, you can try convert `df["time"]` to `string` type by `df["time"] = df["timestamp"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))` and try to plot again `plt.scatter(df['time'], df['energy'])`

Answer (score 0):

First check, if type of `df["timestamp"]` is in datetime format.
if not

```
import pandas as pd  
time = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
print(type(time))
```

Then,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = df['energy']
plt.plot_date(dates , values )
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: df['timestamp'] is already datetime type. and It still plot like second graph.